# Error en array dinámico en c

Tags: array, c

Estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio en c pero no logro entender porque deja de ejecutar luego de poner la cantidad de alumnos. Cabe aclarar que soy una persona iniciando en el mundo de programación y no tengo mucho conocimiento

```
int main()
{
    int espacio, i, x, j, r, u, nota;

    printf("Ingrese la cantida de alumnos: ");
    scanf("%d",&espacio);

    char nombres[espacio];
    float promedios[espacio];

    for(i = 0;i<espacio,i++;){
        printf("\nIngrese el nombre del alumno y sus 6 nota: ");
        scanf("%s",&nombres[i]);

        for(j=0;i<6;j++){
            scanf("%d",&nota);
            nota+=nota;
        }
        for(x=0;i<espacio;x++){
            promedios[x] = nota/6;
        }
    }

    for(u=0;u<espacio;u++){
        printf("ALUMNO: \tPROMEDIO: %f\n",nombres[u],promedios[u]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solamente como comentario, esto es un problema de arreglos estáticos, no dinámicos

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion!

Comment: @EduardoJiménez El tamaño se determina dependiendo de lo que ingrese el usuario, asi que si es un arrelgo dinamico.

Comment: Tienes un error en el `for(i = 0;i<espacio,i++;){`, no debe ir con una coma, debe ir con `;` y el punto y coma del final no es necesario.

Comment: @Pablochaches es diferente que el tamaño del arreglo dependa de un valor variable a que el tamaño del arreglo sea variable, pongo como ejemplo [el artículo de GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-do-dynamic-arrays-work/), donde podemos observar que un arreglo dinámico puede ajustar su tamaño, es decir, puede realocarse en memoria para aumentar o disminuir el tamaño en memoria que ocupa. Lamentablemente no pude encontrar un artículo de una institución sólida que defina un arreglo dinámico, pero verás que el concepto es el mismo

Comment: Como complemento al comentario anterior dejo [este documento](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332683294_La_ensenanza_de_los_arrays_estaticos_dinamicos_y_listas_enlazadas_cual_usar_Analisis_de_codigos_The_teaching_of_static_arrays_dynamics_and_linked_lists_What_to_use_Code_analysis), el cual nos explica un poco acerca de este tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Los problemas

Tu código tienes un montón de errores serios. Y creo que también problemas de
lógica.

Recorriéndolo linea por linea:

---

```
  int espacio, i, x, j, r, u, nota;
```

No declares todas las variables al principio de tu función, esto solo hace que
leer el código sea mas difícil.

Y usualmente es buena idea que siempre inicializes tus variables.

---

```
  char nombres[espacio];
  float promedios[espacio];
```

Aquí tenemos varios problemas:

1. La forma correcta de darle un tamaño dinámicamente a un array es usando
   `malloc`. Lo que tu estas usando es un variable length array, [aqui](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/hf00ak/why_vlas_are_bad/), [aqui](https://www.reidatcheson.com/c/programming/2015/12/07/vlas.html), y [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407754/what-technical-disadvantages-do-c99-style-vlas-have) tienes unos recursos inidicando porque es mala idea usarlos.
2. Supongo que `nombres` tiene que guardar los nombres de los alumnos. En ese
   caso tendría que ser un array bidimensional:

```
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 50

char nombres[espacio][MAX_NAME_SIZE];
```

---

```
  for (i = 0; i < espacio, i++;) {
```

**Este es el motivo por el que se salta al final**. Si te das cuenta entre `i < espacio` y `i++` tienes una `,` no una `;`. Entonces el valor que se toma por
condición del loop es `i++`, que en la primera iteracion sera regresara 0,
saltándose el loop.

---

```
    printf("\nIngrese el nombre del alumno y sus 6 nota: ");
    scanf("%s", &nombres[i]);
```

Lo mismo que comentaba de que nombres tiene que ser un array bidimensional,
cuando pases por aquí lo mejor que puede pasar es que sobrescribas el nombre de
el estudiante anterior. Pero al final vas a parar tocando memoria que no es
tuya.

---

```
    for (j = 0; i < 6; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &nota);
      nota += nota;
    }
```

Aquí tenemos varios errores:

1. La condición del loop depende de `i` no de `j`. Esto hará que cuando lo
   ejecutes sea un ciclo infinito
2. No llevas ningún registro de la suma de las notas. Simplemente a nota le
   sumas nota y en la siguiente vuelta sobrescribes el valor.

---

```
    for (x = 0; i < espacio; x++) {
      promedios[x] = nota / 6;
    }
```

Otro loop infinito (vuelves a usar `i` en lugar de `x`), y en caso de que fuera
correcto, lo que haría es sobrescribir los promedios que ya tienes guardados.

---

```
  for (u = 0; u < espacio; u++) {
    printf("ALUMNO: \tPROMEDIO: %f\n", nombres[u], promedios[u]);
  }
```

Estas omitiendo la impresión del alumno, tendera que ser:

```
    //               |- Notese el %s
    printf("ALUMNO: %s\tPROMEDIO: %f\n", nombres[u], promedios[u]);
```

## Recomendaciones

#### 1. Estudiar (Con buenos recursos)

Lo que veo en ese código son muy malas bases de programación. Si no has estado
prestando atención en clase, es buen momento para empezar, y si si lo has
estado haciendo, creo que es momento de investigar por tu cuenta también.

Te recomendaría el curso gratuito de Harvard
[cs50](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhQjrBD2T382_R182iC2gNZI9HzWFMC_8),
este te dará unas bases fuertes de programación, y tiene el plus de que la
primera parte se imparte en C, lo que te vendrá bien para lo que estas
haciendo.

Esto te ayudara con la mayoría de los problemas, y te hará dejar malas
practicas.

#### 2. Aprende a colocar los avisos en tu compilador

El compilar tu código con avisos trajo a la vista de forma rápida los problemas
mas grandes con tu código:

Estos son los avisos:

```
main.c:13:26: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   for (i = 0; i < espacio, i++;) {
                          ^
main.c:27:34: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
     printf("ALUMNO: \tPROMEDIO: %f\n", nombres[u], promedios[u]);
                                 ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~
                                 %d
main.c:27:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     printf("ALUMNO: \tPROMEDIO: %f\n", nombres[u], promedios[u]);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:27:34: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
     printf("ALUMNO: \tPROMEDIO: %f\n", nombres[u], promedios[u]);
                                 ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~
                                 %d
main.c:27:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     printf("ALUMNO: \tPROMEDIO: %f\n", nombres[u], promedios[u]);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:5:25: warning: unused variable 'r' [-Wunused-variable]
   int espacio, i, x, j, r, u, nota;
```

De hecho, si aprendes a usar un analizador estático, mucho mejor.

#### 3. No copies y pegues código

Los problemas que tienes con los 2 loops internos, parecen porque copiaste el
loop de afuera y no lo modificaste correctamente.

Acostúmbrate a no copiar código.